Is there any convenient way to find the goroutine's parent caller stack?
My business code has some bugs,the Mysql transaction not release, I found goroutines leak through /pprof/goroutine?debug=1 and /pprof/goroutine?debug=2.
10 @ 0x104b7a7a8 0x104b44004 0x104b43bc4 0x1054075e8 0x104bb5094
#        0x1054075e7        database/sql.(*Tx).awaitDone+0x37        /opt/homebrew/opt/go/libexec/src/database/sql/sql.go:2202

The parent goroutine ID can be found, but the stack info is too little.
goroutine 638612 [chan receive]:
database/sql.(*Tx).awaitDone(0x14000492000)
        /opt/homebrew/opt/go/libexec/src/database/sql/sql.go:2202 +0x38
created by database/sql.(*DB).beginDC in goroutine 638919
        /opt/homebrew/opt/go/libexec/src/database/sql/sql.go:1915 +0x1ac

The source code can be found at src/database/sql/sql.go:1915.
// beginDC starts a transaction. The provided dc must be valid and ready to use.
func (db *DB) beginDC(ctx context.Context, dc *driverConn, release func(error), opts *TxOptions) (tx *Tx, err error) {
    // ...

    // Schedule the transaction to rollback when the context is canceled.
    // The cancel function in Tx will be called after done is set to true.
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    tx = &Tx{
        db:                 db,
        dc:                 dc,
        releaseConn:        release,
        txi:                txi,
        cancel:             cancel,
        keepConnOnRollback: keepConnOnRollback,
        ctx:                ctx,
    }
    go tx.awaitDone()
    return tx, nil
}

How to find the caller stack related to the higher-level business code, and who started this transaction?

once a goroutine has started, there is no relationship to the calling code, so the stack of the goroutine in created by is no longer the same, or may not even exist at all.

The last point made by JimB is of the utmost importance: the go statement spawns a new goroutine to run the specified function and immediately finishes, returning control to the next statement in the executing goroutine. There might be no such statement meaning the calling goroutine exits or it may be return meaning it exits as well.
